# How to receive email from hotmail via IMAP and OAuth?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, jakarta-mail, hotmail

I want to receive Email from Hotmail by IMAP, but I have to authenticate by OAuth. From the Microsoft documentation, it supports that, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440163.aspx;

But I have to idea how to use it in java (by Javamail). I tried to use google code sample (correct email and access_toket), but failed.

```
String email = "stony@hotmail.com";
String oauthToken = "XXXXXXXX";

initialize();

IMAPStore imapStore = connectToImap("imap-mail.outlook.com",
                                    993,
                                    email,
                                    oauthToken,
                                    true);
System.out.println("Successfully authenticated to IMAP.\n");


Folder folder =  imapStore.getDefaultFolder();
folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);  //****The linke throw exception****
for (Message msg : folder.getMessages()) {
    String subject = msg.getSubject();
    System.out.println(":" + subject);
}
```

The log printed on system console is,

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4
DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG: enable SASL
DEBUG: SASL mechanisms allowed: XOAUTH2
* OK Outlook.com IMAP4rev1 server version 17.4.0.0 ready (DUB451-IMAP183)
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN ID NAMESPACE UIDPLUS UNSELECT AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed
IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: PLAIN
IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG: protocolConnect login, host=imap-mail.outlook.com, user=mebeautyful@hotmail.com, password=<non-null>
IMAP SASL DEBUG: Mechanisms: XOAUTH2
IMAP SASL DEBUG: SASL client XOAUTH2
A1 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2
+ 
IMAP SASL DEBUG: challenge:  :
IMAP SASL DEBUG: callback length: 1
IMAP SASL DEBUG: callback 0: javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback@61ead9ba
IMAP SASL DEBUG: response: user=mebeautyful@hotmail.comauth=Bearer 

DEBUG: connection available -- size: 1
A2 EXAMINE ""
A1 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] OAuth authentication failed.
A2 BAD Examine Command is not permitted in current state (NotAuthenticated)
A3 LOGOUT
* BYE Logout requested
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: A2 BAD Examine Command is not permitted in current state (NotAuthenticated);
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.iap.BadCommandException: A2 BAD Examine Command is not permitted in current state (NotAuthenticated)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:829)
    at com.google.code.samples.oauth2.OAuth2Authenticator.main(OAuth2Authenticator.java:155)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.iap.BadCommandException: A2 BAD Examine Command is not permitted in current state (NotAuthenticated)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.handleResult(Protocol.java:296)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.examine(IMAPProtocol.java:636)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:811)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested successfully! I verified 3 things,

1. We can use google code sample to collection to outlook's IMAP.  The sample code link is https://code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/wiki/JavaSampleCode
2. Must use the scope wl.imap and wl.offline_access
3. In my hotmail acccount doesn't work, I can't even get a access_token; but after I use my another live account, it works.

Comment: you sure that your answer in section "1" working on hotmail?

Comment: @matant yes, I'm sure it still works in live. didn't try hotmail account.

Comment: how do i use the scope wl.imap and wl.offline_access? should it be part of my java code?

Comment: do you have the code that u executed on the live account?

Answer (score 0):

You're using an older version of JavaMail.  If you use the [latest](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Download_JavaMail_1.5.2_Release) version, [OAuth2 support is built in](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2).

Comment: I justed tried javamail 1.5.2, <dependency>
 <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
 <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
 <version>1.5.2</version>; but doesn't work.
</dependency>

Comment: As it says on the [JavaMail project page](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home), javax.mail-api is "The JavaMail API definitions only, suitable for compiling against".  You want com.sun.mail:javax.mail, which is "The JavaMail reference implementation jar file, including the SMTP, IMAP, and POP3 protocol providers".